# IRC Chat for iPhone sdk?

Tags: web-services, parsing, ios4, uiwebview, xml-parsing

I am planning to make an application with my friend. in this application there will IRC chat.. is there any one who could possibly give me a sample application for this. thanks 
TC

Answer (score 1):

[Mobile Colloquy](http://colloquy.mobi/) is [open source](http://colloquy.info/project/browser/trunk/Mobile).